# Set focus on email address field on the Login Page

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, login, accessibility

I hate using mouse to select a form once I load any webpage which I know will require input of some type, so I just place both of my hands on keyboard and get ready to hit tab until I get to form fields.

But in the case with Stack Overflow it requires 20 tabs (if I counted correctly)

So my suggestion is simple:

Can we consider to set the focus on the email address field after page load?

Comment: I hate it when sites put my cursor somewhere without my knowledge. Just because you're too lazy to use your mouse does not mean that everyone else should have poor UX.

Comment: You are missing the point , i am not saying that cursor should be "pulled" , its just that form get focused.
Anyway , what are you even doing on login page , if you aren't going to login ?

Comment: @Tiny `Just because you're too lazy to use your mouse` that's hardly a valid argument. Some people can't, or simply don't, use a mouse in their workflow. Placing input focus on the element that it's most likely to be needed in is really basic usability, no?

Comment: @Pekka the number of upvotes on that comment (and the number of downvotes on this feature) show how few developers actually understand UX, sadly

Comment: @RayNicholus:  I was more agreeing with the notion that the site puts a cursor somewhere without my knowledge.  Then again, I've seldom had to log in with my email address, so I suppose I'm unclear as to how this might be jarring.

Comment: @Makoto The second sentence in Pekka's comment explains one big reason why focusing on the first field in a form is proper UX.

Comment: I'm surprised there aren't more people who want this. I'm also surprised that this is the first time the topic come up. I wrote a [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-cursor/gjaabiillfmidpcknchjeiadoppocmaf) and [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/auto-cursor/) extension/addon to address this issue globally across the internet. That said, I would rather that all website login and search page forms did this automatically.

Answer (score -3):

Doesn't look like this is ever going to happen @Sutekh, it's so frustrating. I've had to install the Greasemonkey extension -- with this code snippet `document.getElementById(*input ID*).focus();` -- as this UX problem is so common. Why do so many sites fail to use the autofocus attribute? It's just baffling. If I could edit your question I'd add accessibility as a tag.

Comment: _Doesn't look like this is ever going to happen_ Anything to back that up? Just curious, don't take it personal..

Comment: Everything takes 6 to 8 weeks here ...

Comment: @FirstOne It's been 2 years... I'm not trying to knock anyone but if its not happened after 2 years it's obviously not seen as valuable feedback on the UI. I mean it's such a simple thing to implement isn't it?

Comment: I admire your optimism @rene but it's been 108 weeks mate.

Comment: @DragonFist you missed a [meme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514) ...

Comment: @DragonFist yeah, but my question was meant to sound in a way that it seemed like you knew something more than just the time factor. Nevermind, then.

Comment: Oh banter @rene... I get it, good one. Oh and thanks for going easy on a newbie, I see from your link there's also a Greasemonkey meme.