# Autofocus the 'email' field on login page

Tags: feature-request, user-experience, login, accessibility

Apparently, this was asked 5 years ago:

[Set focus on email address field on the Login Page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309226/set-focus-on-email-address-field-on-the-login-page)

If you're like me, you hate using the mouse.

I keep my browser secure on my work computer, so I have to re-login into things manually on sites, like Stack Overflow and I always have to use my mouse to select the email field.

Tabbing to the field? Yeah, it takes 15 tabs to select it.

Big deal? No. Accessibility problem? Sort of.

Every time I log in I just cringe because it's such an expected user experience on login/signup forms and it takes adding just one attribute to the input element. Also, I know that a good portion of the Stack Overflow community uses vim, hates using the mouse, likes to type fast/ go fast.

I also emailed Stack Overflow about this over a year ago and never got a response.

Comment: Good lord, I thought 15 was hyperbole. It literally takes *12 tabs* to get to the email field on https://stackoverflow.com/users/login.

Comment: It takes me 15 tabs - i use brave/chromium on mac os

Comment: Agreed that this is fixworthy but I would have left out the "I hate to use the mouse" first world problem though; it makes it exceptionally hard to have sympathy for the request :) The login form doesn't autofocus the username field, nuff said.